# new attribute in laravel collection object to return in JSON

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am returning post categories (M:M relationship) in a API and i need the categories to come as comma separated value
in a new attribute called category_csv

i am setting public `$category_csv` in the model and looping through the collections in the 
controller and assigning the csv values to this attribute

in the controller this is how i get the products with categories `Product::with(['categories'])->get()`

is this the best way to do this?

Comment: have you created resource for it? or you have returned it in the normal controller?

Comment: Add your code please for the api resource

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json

You can append values to your JSON using this way, here is an example.

in the model you can define `protected $appends = ['category_csv'];`

and define a new method in the model

```
/**
     * Get product categories in csv format.
     */
    public function getCategoryCsvAttribute()
    {
        $product_category = [];
        foreach ($this->categories as $category) {
            $product_category[] = $category->name;
        }
        return $this->category_csv = implode(',', $product_category);
    }
```

Now when you try to call your API get method, along with what it returned it will return this new attribute with the CSV value